# wordpress contact form template

Tags: wordpress, templates, contacts

I've designed a contact form template with the help of a tutorial and then added the template to a page. I'm trying to show error message if any field is empty or show a success message instead. It is showing the error messages correctly, but when all the fields are entered it's showing a blank page. couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my entire code.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact
*/

?>

<?php
$msgSubmission = false;
$nameError = '';
$emailError = '';
$commentError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    if(trim($_POST['name']) === '') {
        $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
        $hasError = true;
    }else if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
    }

    if((isset($name) && $name!='') && (isset($email) && $email!='') && (isset($comments) && $comments!='')) {
        $msgSubmission = true;
    }

} ?>

<?php get_header();?>
<div id="post_container">
    <div id="left_part">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php if(isset($msgSubmission) && $msgSubmission == true) { ?>
                <div class="thanks"><br /><br />Thanks, your message was sent successfully.<br /><br /></div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <form action="<?php the_permalink()?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <!--    <label for="contactName">Name:</label>  -->
                        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="errorMsg"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <input type="text" class="txtinput" placeholder="Your name" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name']))  echo $_POST['name'];?>" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <!--    <label for="email">Email</label>    -->
                        <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="errorMsg"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <input type="text" class="txtinput" placeholder="Your e-mail address" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <!--    <label for="commentsText">Message:</label>  -->
                        <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                        <span class="errorMsg"><?php echo $commentError;?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <textarea class="txtblock" placeholder="Enter a cool message..." name="comment" id="comment" rows="15" cols="55">
                        <?php if(isset($_POST['comment']))  echo $_POST['comment'];?>
                        </textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Message!"></input>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- .post -->
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .left_part -->
    <?php get_sidebar();?>
    <div class="separator"></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all add this line to the top of your script.

```
$hasError = false;
```

Then use this block of code where you want to show success message.

```
if(!$hasError) {
// display success message.
}
```

Hope this may help you.